# MySQL joining two tables where record not exist in the other table

Tags: mysql, join, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have two tables

1. first table is called ps_cart
2. second table is called ps_orders

ps_cart has this columns:

1. id_cart (PK)
   and so on...

ps_orders has this columns:

1. id_order (PK)
2. id_cart

Basically i want to show all abandon cart, that is JOIN both table where id_order is null.

I thought this can be achieve using OUTER JOIN like so..

```
SELECT cr.id_cart, o.id_order, cr.id_carrier, cr.id_address_delivery, cr.id_customer, cr.date_upd
FROM ps_cart AS cr
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_orders AS o ON cr.id_cart = o.id_cart
WHERE cr.date_upd BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-02-29"
ORDER BY cr.date_upd DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Yet i still on the result where id_order is not null (meaning an order has been created/completed). I am expecting to get null value on the id_order.

I can "cheat" my way around by adding the WHERE id_order = NULL clause, but i feel that this may not be the best approach.

Can anyone help me or explain it to me why OUTER JOIN is not working as i expected? Am i missing something ?

**EDIT**
I know what i want, it is LEFT EXCLUDING JOIN
so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT cr.id_cart, o.id_order, o.current_state, cr.id_carrier, cr.id_address_delivery, cr.id_customer, cr.date_upd
FROM ps_cart AS cr
LEFT JOIN ps_orders AS o ON cr.id_cart = o.id_cart
WHERE o.id_cart IS NULL
AND cr.date_upd BETWEEN "2016-02-01" AND "2016-02-29"
ORDER BY cr.date_upd DESC;
```

Please see image below to better illustrate what i mean.

[image: OUTER JOIN]

Answer (score 0):

Basically joins are search on some key

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_orders AS o ON cr.id_cart = o.id_cart
```

at here, it will consider only those cr.id_cart which are matched with other table, null will be ignored.

Comment: How can i achieve the exact opposite ? That is i want to get cr.id_cart which return null on the other table